# Android MediaSessionCompat setActive not working

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I've set up a MediaSessionCompat object in my Android project (replacing the RemoteControlClient that I was using).  However no matter what I do, the MediaSessionCompat never gets activated when I call setActive (i.e. isActive() returns false afterward).  Also no exceptions are thrown in my code.

Here's my code:

```
mMediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(m_currentContext, MEDIA_SESSION_TAG);
mMediaSession.setCallback(new RemixMediaSessionCallback());
mMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
mMediaSession.setPlaybackToLocal(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaSession.setActive(true);
```

Does anyone have an idea of what may be missing in my code?

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue. I call setActive, but the none of the media button pressed are handled (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496933/mediastyle-notification-is-not-responding-to-remotecontrol-events)

Comment: I looked in the MediaSessionCompat source code and found that there's no implementations available yet except for Lollipop (which basically just calls MediaSession). So basically, the functions are all stubs that do nothing. Calling setActive just sets the internal "isActive" flag to false.  It would have been nice if the MediaSessionCompat online documentation indicated this.  So what I had to do is keep my RemoteControlClient code for pre-Lollipop devices.  And for Lollipop, I implemented MediaSessionCompat.

Comment: Yeah, this behavior was actually confirmed by the Android DevRel here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474227/how-to-use-mediasessioncompat-and-keep-backward-compatibility-with-remotecontrol. However, did you actually get the media buttons to respond to events on Lollipop when using MediaSessionCompat?

Comment: I have the same problem here. I was using AudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver to receive the headset clicks, but this doesn't work anymore on Lollipop. So, i started to update my code to use both AudioManager on API Level < 21 and MediaSession on API Level 21 or greater, but with no success until now. How did you manage to do this Dan ?

Comment: Did you try to follow the advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27046548/1390874